# firebase set doesn't allow me to write more data

Tags: database, firebase, web

I am trying so long to write into my database the simplest data using javascript to do so, but i tried so many ways it seems i can't do it, i was writing in my firebase just this three values coming from a submit button in my webpage:

```
var user = document.getElementById("usuario").textContent;
var msn = $("#usermsg").val();
var d = new Date();
var t = d.getTime();
firebase.database().ref('chat_room/'+user+'/'+t).set({
message : msn,
sender : server,
receiver : user
});
```

firebase database result:

```
-KwRbHu2cHj5rXo1GDeH
    message: "5"
    receiver: "ipm9KUXcReSGHzFCFxWbwyU61Bb2"
    sender: "server"
```

and this is working just fine, but i tried to change it like this and it never work again:

```
 var chatFire = firebase.database().ref().child('chat_room').child(user).push();
 console.log('push: '+chatFire);
 chatFire.set({
 message:msn,
 sender:server,
 receiver:user,
 hora:t
 });
```

and the result it's just the same as the code above this one, doesn't take the key "hora", just the first three, and even if i change a letter from the key for example "sender" to "senderx" it doesn't take this as well just the other two:

firebase result

```
 -KwRbJrbymfOs0jPOUwe
     message: "hghg"
     receiver: "ipm9KUXcReSGHzFCFxWbwyU61Bb2"
```

It seems that it's taken a format from somewhere like a pojo or something, but there is nothing in my entire code that is controlling this data, please help!

Just to add more info my Rules in FirebaseDatabase are allowing write and read for all, so that is not the problem.

thanks in advance!!

Comment: try doing `var userRef = firebase.database().ref().child('chat_room').child(user)` and then `var chatFire = userRef.push()` and then continue the code from there

Comment: thanks for answering, but the problem is the same with that, still only saving this three keys: message, sender, receiver;no matter what i put instead of those , only those are recognized by set function,

Comment: is it maybe the datetime you have to convert to iso string? `chatFire.set({
 message:msn,
 sender:server,
 receiver:user,
 hora:t.toISOString();
 });`

Comment: Thanks for help, but is not, it's happening even with every other random data, if I change the key message for: message1, the same happens doesn't take that key any more, just the other two, like a pojo or something